# How can i output my content in pairs?

Tags: forloop

how can i output my content in pairs?

like this:

```
div.row >   entry 1 + entry 2
div.row >   entry 3 + entry 4
div.row >   entry 5 + entry 6
```

so far i have the following

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.find({section:'events' ,level: 2 }) %}
<div class="row">

    {% if loop.index0 is divisible by(2) %}
    (entry odd output here)
    {% endif %}

    {% if loop.index is divisible by(2) %}
    (entry even output here)
    {% endif %}

</div>
{% endfor %}
```

but this just gives me a new row for each entry.
What's the best approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with Twigs [`batch`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/batch.html) filter, which exactly solves your problem.

Here an an adapted example:

```
{% set items = craft.entries({
    section: 'events',
    level: 2
}).find() %}

{% for row in items|batch(2, 'No item') %}
    <div class="row">
        {% for item in row %}
            {# Your entry #}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thx! Almost there.. Alas this outputs the content of my structure level1 n times. Can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: I changed my example slightly to get the entries you ask for. Not tested, but I think this should work. You could also solve it with chaining `{% set items = craft.entries.section('events').level(2).find() %}`.

Comment: No matter how i try to chain it, it keeps giving me the content of the parent. The number of the items is right but not the content. When i wrote `{% for entry in craft.entries.find({section:'events' ,level: 2 }) %}` the output was fine but then i couldn't do an output in batch.

Comment: My bad > i never changed my output code to the new function name. Stupid beginners mistake. thank You much for your help!